# Can't insert Json into database

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to insert `{"0":"1"}` into a mysql database which I thought was straightforward!

I did this:

```
$arr = array('0' => '1');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

But that gives ["1"]

however if I do this:

```
$arr = array('0' => '1',"b" =>"2");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I get this

```
{"0":"1","b":"2"}
```

Can someone help and explain what I need to do to get:

```
{"0":"1"}
```

thanks

Comment: You need json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) as the second parameter to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
$arr = ['0' => '1'];
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

output:

```
{"0":"1"}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/R7OdA)

Answer (score 0):

Use
json_encode($arr, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)